# Grails: Dynamic form

Tags: grails

I have problem with **remove Author from Book**.

I have class Book and class Author in **One-To-Many unidirectional** relationship:

```
class Book{

    String isbn
    ...

    List<Author> authors
    static hasMany = [ authors: Author ]
}

class Author {

    String firstname
    String lastname
    ...

}
```

note: in class Author there is not **belongTo**.

I use dynamic form:
[image]

Please note buttons **Add author** and **Remove author**. I use JavaScript for append html code to form or remove html code from form.

After that I save class Book in controller:

```
 def save = {
            def book = new Book()

            if (params.id){
                book = Book.get(params.id)                     
            }

            book.properties = params

            if( book.save() ){
                redirect(controller:"book", action:"all")
                return
            }else{
                render(view:'form', model:["book": book])
                return
            }
        }
```

**It work well** for **Add author** and for **editing author** but **not for Remove author**.
If I used Remove author button and click submit form, the **author does not remove from Book**.
There are all the authors as before the editing.

Please, can You help my with this problem? 
It is a good solution to this problem?

Thank a lot
Tom

Comment: How did you generate the forms in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for Grails to know which author you are wanting to remove unless you send the ID of the author to remove in your request and an explicit instruction to grails to remove it.  As of right now, no author in params does not mean remove author.

So you would need to do something in your form so that when you "remove an author" you store the id of the author to remove in a hidden field as well as something to indicate it is for removal.  Then something *like*...

```
def authorToRemove = Author.get(params.authorId)
def book = Book.get(params.id)
book.removeFromAuthors(authorToRemove)
```

Comment: Instead of getting the complete object of author, just loading its proxy would also work. def authorToRemove = Author.load(params.authorId)